# Scala Seq comparison

Tags: scala, seq

is there a way in Scala to compare two sequences in a way that it returns true if it contains the same elements, regardless of order and repetitions?

```
Seq("1", "2") vs Seq("2", "1")           => true
Seq("3", "1", "2") vs Seq("2", "1", "3") => true
Seq("1", "1", "2") vs Seq("2", "1")      => true
```

Thanks

ps this is not a duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622895/is-there-an-api-method-that-compares-contents-of-a-seq-irrespective-of-order) because it also asks to exclude duplicated from the check and it is using SEQ instead of LIST.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an API method that compares contents of a Seq irrespective of order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622895/is-there-an-api-method-that-compares-contents-of-a-seq-irrespective-of-order)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert to sets and compare those

Comment: why this answer has been down voted? it seems to work fine

Comment: when converted to sets Seq("1", "1", "2").toSet will be equal to Seq("1","2").toSet because of same elements

Comment: @stanislav.chetvertkov Which in this question seems desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ def sameElements[A](a: Seq[A], b: Seq[A]) = a.toSet == b.toSet
defined function sameElements
@ sameElements(Seq("1", "2"),Seq("2", "1"))
res2: Boolean = true
@ sameElements(Seq("3", "1", "2"),Seq("2", "1", "3"))
res3: Boolean = true
@ sameElements(Seq("1", "1", "2"),Seq("2", "1"))
res4: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Introduce an extension object with === operator.
It will be used implicitly for the same typed Seqs

```
implicit class SeqOps[A](it:Seq[A]){
  def === (that:Seq[A]) = it.toSet == that.toSet
}

import Test.SeqOps

Seq("1", "2") === Seq("2", "1") shouldBe true
```

Answer (score -3):

You just need to turn the sequences to sets:

```
val n1: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 3, 4)
    val n2: Seq[Int] = Seq(3, 4, 1)

    if(n1.toSet.equals(n2.toSet)){
      println("The sequences have the same elements.")
    }
```

Comment: Scala uses == for checking objects structural equality

Comment: link to difference between == and equals (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681161/whats-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-scala)

Comment: @farohetch13 Your own link seems to suggest that `==` is a better method compared to `equals`?  `==` seems to wrap around `equals` but handles null better