# Why does it happen that two Spark dataframe schemata with identical fields are not equal in junit assertions?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, junit, schema

I am doing a unit test, where I check the equality of two Spark dataframes with

```
Assertions.assertEquals(actualDF.schema(), expectedDF.schema());
```

If I print the schemas, they look the same:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- idvalue: string (nullable = true)
 |-- seqvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |-- idconfig: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- idvalue: string (nullable = true)
 |-- seqvalue: long (nullable = true)
 |-- idconfig: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

---

However, I get an error message

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType@55b9ffd0<StructType(StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(idvalue,StringType,true), StructField(seqvalue,LongType,true), StructField(idconfig,StringType,true), StructField(key,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true))> but was: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType@a5f5b96<StructType(StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(idvalue,StringType,true), StructField(seqvalue,LongType,true), StructField(idconfig,StringType,true), StructField(key,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true))>
Expected :StructType(StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(idvalue,StringType,true), StructField(seqvalue,LongType,true), StructField(idconfig,StringType,true), StructField(key,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true))
Actual   :StructType(StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(idvalue,StringType,true), StructField(seqvalue,LongType,true), StructField(idconfig,StringType,true), StructField(key,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true))
```

The only difference I see is that weird number `StructType@55b9ff0` vs. `StructType@a5f5b96` in the first line, from which I don't know what it means and why it is relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two StructType sharing same contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372002/how-to-compare-two-structtype-sharing-same-contents)

Comment: No, I actually care about the column ordering and my column ordering is the same on both schemata. Doesn't explain the error message